# Logical representation of a divisor using only $(=, <, \cdot)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$x$ is a divisor of $y$ (symbols: $=, <, \cdot$) for $\mathbb{N}$.

Does it make sense?

$(\forall y \in \mathbb{N} \quad \exists x,p \in \mathbb{N})(( y = x \cdot p) \wedge (x < y))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have made your question look a bit nicer using MathJax. In the future, you may want to format your questions in this way. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, then $x$ is a divisor of $y$ is equivalent, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y=xn$. Sometimes such that is just indicated with a ,. That's it.

Comment: You don't need the inequality since if $x > y$, then there couldn't exist an $n$ such $nx =y$ since $nx > ny$.